# Rails: `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, sqlite

Ruby: 2.6.2
Rails: 6.0.3.4

I'm trying to run `rails server` and I keep getting this error:

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

My gemfile reads:

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby"
```

I've tried installing sqlite3 to windows manually and tried chaning my gemfile to download version 1.3.11 with no luck.

Comment: have you tried simply, `gem 'sqlite3'`

Comment: @dbugger Just tried it, getting the same error :(

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with Windows. https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b. Try this in the gemfile `gem ‘sqlite3’, git: “https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: “add-gemspec”`

Comment: @dbugge I tried it and didn't manage to get it to work. But probably a blessing in disguise as I've not deployed it on Linux without an issue :) but thanks your help